# Ajax in jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

(All is good now. There was something wrong with my ASP script. Sorry!)

I've wrote the following script, and it's suppose to update the text in a DIV with the classname `.displaymode`, but it wasn't updated. Did I left out something here?

```
//On "Saving Payment Status"
$("input[name=savepaymentstats]").click(function(){ 
    //Some Codes
    $.ajax({
        url:"paymentstatsupdate.asp?mode=haha",
        success:function(result) { 
            $(".displaymode").html(result); 
        }
    });
    $(".displaymode").show();   
});
```

Comment: `displaymode` is a class on your DIV ?

Comment: Start by checking if you included the jquery library in you page

Comment: Any error in console/network tab? Is the click event fired? Is the ajax success callback called? Etc...

Comment: Maybe try `$('input[name="savepaymentstats"]')`

Comment: @putvande `$("input[name=savepaymentstats]")` is valid selector

Comment: Does the returned result contain anything?

Comment: Comment out the whole code and replace it with `$("input[name=savepaymentstats]").click(function(){ alert('Click event works!') });` and see if you get an alert. That's step1 of debugging. Let us know the result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
   $("input[name=savepaymentstats]").click(function(){ 
      $.ajax({url:"paymentstatsupdate.asp?mode=haha",success:function(result) { 
            $(".displaymode").html(result).show(); 
         }
      });
   }); 
});
```

Comment: We can never underestimate the power of DOM ready. Did you miss it?

Comment: Absolutely, i missed that, my bad!